# Knockout - custom foreach binding applying bindings multiple times to the same element

Tags: knockout.js

Using the following custom binding I am receiving the following and I can not figure out why.

*Version* Knockout JavaScript library v3.2.0

> You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

**Binding**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foreachArraySplice = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var columns = allBindings.get('columns') || 1;

        /* Split the array into splices */
        var len = value.length;
        var splitArray = [];
        var i = 0;
        while (i < len) {
            var size = Math.ceil((len - i) / columns--);
            splitArray.push(value.slice(i, i + size));
            i += size;
        }
        /*\Split the array into splices */
        ko.cleanNode(element); // Last attempted fix...
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
            foreach: splitArray
        });
    }
};
```

**Usage**

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreachArraySplice: anArray, columns: 5">
  <div class="col-md-2" data-bind="foreach: $data, css: { first: $index == 0, last: $index == $data.length }">
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" data-bind="value: $data.key" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Reasoning**

In a nutshell I need to take an array of objects (100s) and display them on a page. I use bootstrap so I figured I would make a binding handler that took the array and splice it into smaller arrays within the array based on the `columns` binding, and display them neatly in my view as shown above.

The arrays always vary so I wanted it to be dynamic as possible, but somewhere the code above is causing the aforementioned error. For brevity I did not include my viewModel as it is a standard model with an observable array containing objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell knockout that your binding handler will control the bindings of the descendant elements.  They are effectively being processed twice by knockout, from your call to `applyBindingsToNode()` and through normal knockout processing.

You do so by making your `init()` function return an object with a `controlsDescendantBindings` property set to `true`.  More on that [in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foreachArraySplice = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        // ...
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```